# OCR Hand written data showing error in svm.train()

Tags: python, opencv, svm, ocr, categorical-data

I am using OpenCV3.1.0 with Python2.7 .
I have implemented code of OCR Hand Written Data from [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_svm/py_svm_opencv/py_svm_opencv.html#svm-opencv).

```
responses = np.float32(np.repeat(np.arange(10),250)[:,np.newaxis])
svm.train(trainData,cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, responses)
```

and getting these error

> svm.train(trainData,cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, responses)
>   cv2.error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\ml\src\svm.cpp:1618: error: (-5) in the case of classification problem the responses must be categorical; either specify varType when creating TrainData, or pass integer responses in function cv::ml::SVMImpl::train

Note: Since working on opencv3.x I have used cv2.ml.svm wherever necessary and rest is same

And if using

```
responses = np.int32(np.repeat(np.arange(10),250)[:,np.newaxis])
```

getting 0 accuracy

Answer (score -1):

Try using `pytesseract`. It is much better than training an SVM classifier. If you want to check it out, follow this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract/0.1)). Also for an advanced example check out this [site](https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-a-simple-ocr-server/) as well.

Comment: This isn't an anwer on the question asked (how to get SVM training for classification working). It's a suggestion on an alternative technique, and could be a comment. Neither do you specify why pytesseract would be better.